# Fusion 2-categories for string-like excitations: a more concrete description?

Tags: mathematical-physics, topological-field-theory, topological-order, anyons, category-theory

I'm familiar with how fusion categories describe the fusion of point-like excitations, and how braided fusion categories describe the fusion of anyons in 2+1D topological order. Concretely, a fusion category can be described by two sets of data: a finite set $S$ of particle types with fusion rules $$a\times b=\sum_{c\in S}N_{ab}^c c, ~~\forall a,b\in S,$$
and the $F$-matrix describing the natural isomorphism $(a\times b)\times c\cong a\times(b\times c)$: [image: Change of basis: F-matrix]

[Fusion 2-categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.11933) are proposed to describe the fusion of string-like excitations in 3+1D topological order [see [Wen2018](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.8.021074) and [Wen2019]](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.9.021005). However, the references all appear to be very abstract, and I want to know a more concrete description of fusion 2-categories. In particular, what are the generalizations of fusion rules, $F$-matrices, and the pentagon equation in fusion 2-categories?

Comment: In the recent preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.15947 they calculated the fusion rule explicitly in fusion $2$-category of super vector spaces. I think the pentagon axiom is inherently a (monoidal) categorical construction so it wouldn't change if you pass it through higher dimension. Also, the higher dimensional analogue of $F$-matrix in $1$-category is the $10j$-symbol in $2$-category.